# What is incorrect with my Voronoi generator?

Tags: java, algorithm, voronoi

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Voronoi
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

        Point[] points = new Point[50];

        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new Point(r.nextInt(500), r.nextInt(500));
        }

        int b = Color.BLUE.getRGB();
        int w = Color.WHITE.getRGB();
        int g = Color.GREEN.getRGB();


        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            buf.setRGB(points[i].x, points[i].y, b);
        }

        ArrayList<Point> dis = new ArrayList<Point>();
        int min = 5000;

        for(int i = 0; i < buf.getWidth(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < buf.getHeight(); j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < points.length; k++)
                {
                    if(buf.getRGB(i, j) == b)
                        continue;

                    int d = distance(i, points[k].x, j, points[k].y);

                    if(d == min)
                    {
                        dis.add(points[k]);
                    }
                    else if(d < min)
                    {
                        dis.clear();
                        dis.add(points[k]);
                        min = d;
                    }

                }

                if(dis.size() == 1)
                {
                        buf.setRGB(i, j, w);
                }
                else if(dis.size() > 1)
                {
                    Point m = midPoint(dis);

                    buf.setRGB(m.x, m.y, g);
                }

                dis.clear();
                min = 5000;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            ImageIO.write(buf, "png", new File("this.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        return (int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    }

    public static Point midPoint(ArrayList<Point> p)
    {
        int totX = 0;
        int totY = 0;

        for(Point a: p)
        {
            totX += a.x;
            totY += a.y;
        }

        totX /= p.size();
        totY /= p.size();

        return new Point(totX, totY);
    }
}
```

All it generates is something like this:

[image]

What the code is supposed to be doing:
Go through each pixel, one by one, and find the point(s) [The blue dots] closest to each pixel. If there is only one point, color that pixel white. However if there are multiple points, color that green.

Comment: The error is the output itself, blue points are center, green points are supposed to be the boundaries, and yet I'm only getting a series of points.

Comment: I'd restructure this question a bit in order to get better feedback. State a) what the algorithm is exactly supposed to do (if you write to two sentences about that, you may get feedback from all the people who might be able to help but don't know what a Voronoi generator's supposed to do) b) explain in simple words how your algorithm works. then c) try to say as precisely as possible what goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what was wrong:

Originally:

```
int d = distance(i, points[k].x, j, points[k].y);
```

The correct version:

```
int d = distance(i, j, points[k].x, points[k].y);
```

In addition to that, I was not supposed to be averaging the correct points as I was here:

```
Point m = midPoint(dis);
```

I was supposed to merely color (i,j) green.